# Why is optimizing the value function $V^\pi(s)$ for $\pi$ the same as optimizing the Q-function $Q^\pi(s,a)$ for $\pi$?

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

I know that in reinforcement learning the value function $V^\pi(s)$ and the Q-function $Q^\pi(s,a)$ are related by the formula

$$V^\pi(s) = \sum_a \pi(s,a) Q^\pi(s,a)$$

(where $\pi(s,a)$ is often written as $\pi(a|s)$). One is usually interested in finding a policy/control law that maximizes the expected discounted reward for a given state; i.e., one seeks $\pi^\star$ such that

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_t \gamma^tR_t^\pi\right] = V^\pi(s_t)\rightsquigarrow \max_{\pi}$$

which means one wants to find $V^\star$. An alternative to finding an optimal value function is to find an optimal Q-function $Q^\star$ via

$$Q^\pi(s_t,a) \rightsquigarrow \max_\pi$$

for all actions $a$ in $s_t$. I recently realized that I have simply accepted that every $\pi^\star_Q$ that optimally solves the Q-function for all states and actions also is an optimal policy $\pi^\star_V$ under the value function and vice versa, but I was wondering if this could be formally proven.

Is it possible to prove that both optimization problems are equivalent?